# Tree-Structures & SQL - Looking for design recommendations

Tags: sql, tree

from what I've researched so far, this topic is both well documented and very broad. So I'm hoping you can safe me some time diving into the depths of how to store trees in a database by pointing me in the right direction.

I'm working with questionnaires, similarly to how HL7/FHIR approach them:There's two classes: Questionnaire and Item, with Questionnaire consisting of a Set of Items. However, Items can refer to any number of additional Items (i.e. children).So basically, I have a n-ary tree-like structure with - depending on how you want to look at it -a) a Questionnaire-Object as root and several Items as childrenb) several Items as a root each (i.e. a forest), again each with several Items as children

```
class Questionnaire {
    items: Set<Item>

    inner class Item {
        children: Set<Item>
    }
}
```

This part of the data structure unfortunately is non-negotiable (other than the use of inner classes, which I could change).

I'm now looking for a sensible way to store such a structure in my database (currently MySQL).

Luckily, I'm only ever storing and reading the whole questionnaire. I do not need to access individual nodes or branches, and the data will not be changed / updated (because any change to an existing Questionnaire will result in a new Questionnaire as per my projects definition). So I only need to work with SELECT and INSERT statements, each for one complete Questionnaire (with all its items).

My first approach was to reverse the Item-to-Item relationship, i.e. referring to one parent rather than several children. However, I fear that this might be hell to translate back into the already fixed object-structure. I'm hoping for a fairly easy solution.

Please note that I am aware that there's probably really nice solutions using ORM, but I've been having trouble wrapping my head around the whole setup progress lately, and am now too pressed for time to get into that. Right now, I need a solution in plain SQL to show results. ORM will have to wait a little, but I will get back to that!Also note that performance does not matter right now.

Thanks in advance for your efforts, your help will be much apreciated!

Comment: MySQL supports storing data as JSON-formatted Strings. Since my data has to be representable as JSON anyways, and since I only write and read the entire (nested) Object, couldn't I circumvent the design problem by just making use of that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing in case anyone else is looking for an answer:

Let's take as an example my `QuestionnaireResponse` class:

```
data class QuestionnaireResponse (
    val qID: String, 
    val timeStamp: String,
    val items: List<Item> = listOf<Item>()) {

    inner class Item (val itemID: String, val itemType: String, var unit: String,
                      var answers: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf())
}
```

Where `qID` references the `Questionnaire` that has been answered here.
When a `Questionnaire` is answered, I'll receive the above object in JSON. I decided to parse the incoming JSON to my data structure, extract `qID` and `timeStamp`, and store those values in my database. That way I can select only those `QuestionnaireResponses` answering to a specific `Questionnaire`, and filter by `timeStamp`, while still circumventing to try and represent that (basically recursive) structure into my Db.

The SQL code to create the corresponding table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `questionnaireresponses` (
  `questionnaireID` int NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `questionnaireResonseObject` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`questionnaireID`,`timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `answeredQuestionnaire` FOREIGN KEY (`questionnaireID`) REFERENCES `questionnaires` (`id`))
```

From what I read, not all databases support the `json` data type. What it does in MySQL is making sure that the inserted data is formatted properly. I never mind additional checks, but since I've already been successfully parsing the JSON in my application before inserting it into the Db, that step can be omitted. Thus, if your Db doesn't support the `json`-type, any type that allows to store strings of variable length (e.g. text or blob) might work as well.